# Save hyperlink URL's from selected text?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Is it possible to only store URLs of currently selected text?

This saves selected text on page

```
var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
```

and this saves ALL hyperlinks

```
var links = document.links;
```

Edit:
This returns `null`:

```
var data=new Object();
    data.selectedText = window.getSelection();
    console.log(data.selectedText.outerHTML);
```

Comment: You'd have to run a regular expression on `window.getSelection()` to pick out links.

Comment: How can i extract data from `window.getSelection()`? tried `.outerHTML` but it's `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get links that are in "a" tags you can just do something like this:

```
function getLinksFromSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
            var links = div.getElementsByTagName("A")
            for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
                console.log(links[i].href);
            }
    }
}
```

If you also want to take into account a selection that is contained within a link (i.e. the link is a parent node to the selection) then you'd add something like this:

```
var alink = range.commonAncestorContainer;
if (alink.nodeType == 3) {
    // if text node then get parent
    alink = alink.parentNode;
}
if (alink.tagName === 'A') {
    console.log(alink.href)
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ESr3C/

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLinks() {

    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

    regex = new RegExp(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/gim);

    var result;
    while((result = regex.exec(selectedText)) !== null) {
       console.log(result[1])
    }
}
```

Comment: This writes the found links to the console, but you can always store in an array.